# Scene3D cause application crash after upgrading project from Qt5.9 to Qt5.15

Tags: qt, qt5

I have been working on upgrading a Qt Quick project from Qt5.9 to Qt5.15 in Ubuntu22.04. The project can be compiled and run in Qt5.15, but it will crash after being started. it shows error as below:
[image]

After some testing on the code, I found it is Scene3D that caused the application crashing: if I comment the component using Scene3D, the application works fine. The Scene3D related code are used to read .obj file and display some 3D model

```
    Scene3D{
        anchors.fill: parent
        Entity {
            id: sceneRoot
            Camera {
                id: camera
                projectionType: CameraLens.OrthographicProjection   
                nearPlane : 0.1 
                farPlane : 1000.0
                position: Qt.vector3d( 150, 0, 1 ) 
                upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0, 1.0, 0 )    
            }

            components: [
                RenderSettings{
                    activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer{
                        clearColor:  Qt.rgba(0,0.5,1,0);
                        camera: camera
                    }
                },

                InputSettings{}
            ]

            //ground
            Mesh {
                id: meshG
                source: "file:///home/chin/teachbox/joint-model/ground.obj"
            }

            Transform{
                id:torTransformG
                property real hAngle:0.0
                translation: Qt.vector3d(1,-60,1) //(x,y,z)
            }

            PhongAlphaMaterial {
                id: materialG
                ambient:"#F1F1F1"
                alpha: 1.0
            }

            Entity {
                id: entityG
                components: [meshG, materialG,torTransformG]
            }

            ....  // there are more entities like above

       }
   }
```

I also tried to extract Scene3D related code to a seperated project, those codes worked fine, *the application will not crash*.

So What the real root of such problem and how could I sovle it?